# Holder.js in Google Appengine (python)

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine, holder.js

I want to load a placeholder image using `holder.js` in a static template. In static template `index.html` I have:

```
<img src="/static/holder.js/200x200">
```

I have handlers set in `app.yaml` for serving static files in a folder called `static`, so I know that's not  a problem, but for some reason `holder.js` will not generate the 200x200 image I called for (the log files generate a 404 error). I bet this is some sort of handler issue; perhaps App Engine is treating my request as a directory and cannot find it. I need to configure the `app.yaml` file so that it treats requests to `holder.js` as a parameter for the file and not as a subdirectory of the file. Can someone point me in the right direction to help solve this problem?

Comment: Are you including the script as well?

Comment: Do I have to do add a script handler separately from the directory handler?

Comment: No, I meant in your template. Do you have `<script src="/static/holder.js"></script>`?

Comment: Yes, I do have the script included. Does its position in the document matter?

Comment: It shouldn't. What happens if you go directly to /static/holder.js in your browser?

Comment: I can see the source code of holder.js when I do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Holder.js, the `src` attribute isn't meant to be used as a real URI. Instead, it's used as an identifier for Holder.js (specifically the `domain` option). Your code should look like this: `<img src="holder.js/200x200">` or `<img data-src="holder.js/200x200">`. Make sure to include `<script src="/static/holder.js"></script>` in the document as well.